# use of undeclared identifier '_bridge'

Tags: objective-c, c

My objective-c project contains C libraries that has:

```
void* ptr;
```

ViewController has:

```
UIImageView pic;
pic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ground.png"]];

cLoad cload; // C-class object
cload.ptr = (_bridge void*) pic;
```

I use ARC but i don't understand why I'm getting error message: `use of undeclared identifier bridge`
Thank you )))

Answer (score 2):

```
cload.ptr = (__bridge void*) pic;
```

**__bridge**, with two underscores...